# jQuery animate once when page load and show animated destination on rest of pages

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/zTTxu/

How can I animate once when page1 load example: animate 'a' to 'b' destination and save 'b' destination and when goes to next page2 animation will not going to start again it should show the animated 'b' destination? Please show me some sample on fiddle thx.

Comment: For saving any data to use other pages, you need server side manipulation or set cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to load new css on page 2, 3 etc. (the final css properties of the previous page) and create a new click event for each page.